# jqgrid callback function after save

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the following snippet to call manually call the save function on the grid. I'm using inline editing.
The save function needs to return a custom object. How do I access the return value? Is there a callback function? Does the successfunc only return true/false?

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('saveRow',rowid, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc,errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);
```

Comment: it's important to know whether you use local editing of grid or use `saveRow` tosave the data to the server. In the second case the saving works typically asynchronously. Where exactly you need to use the data returned from the server? Typically the server returns sometimes some additional information which need be saved somewhere in the grid or somewhere on the page. What is your case?

Comment: Hi Oleg! I'm just starting on jqgrid. This is what I have so far.    `jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('saveRow', 'new_row','','clientArray', '', MySaveFunction, '', ''); I have a custom button (in addition to Add, Edit etc..) in the top navigation bar. When this custom button is clicked, it needs to save the record and perform another operation back to back. For the second operation, I need the rowid of the record that was previously savd. I was not able to get the rowid, so I was hoping to own custom id and pass it back to the caller.

Comment: My goal is manually trigger the Save function, and trigger another function for the second operation. I'm not able to do them both back-to-back as the second operation needs the rowid of the newly saved record. It cannot proceed with just 'new_row' for rowid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `saveRow` to save the local data you can just set the value of some external variable (the variable defined in the outer scope) inside of your `mySaveFunction`. It's important only to understand, that you have to use `aftersavefunc` parameter of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) (or [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow)) instead of `succesfunc` parameter. It's typical misunderstanding, but the `succesfunc` callback will be called *only in case of saving the data on the server*. The `succesfunc` callback will be not called in case of `'clientArray'`. I recommend you to use "object" form of the `editRow` usage:

```
var someRetValue;
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('saveRow', rowid,
{
    url: 'clientArray'
    aftersavefunc: function (id, response, options) {
        someRetValue = response; // set someRetValue to any value
    }
});
```

On the other side you can consider to use callback functions as the parameter of your own `"Save"` function. If the `"Save"` will have `afterSaveFunc` parameter you will not need to use any return value of the `"Save"` function. You should just build your JavaScript script to work asynchronous instead of the classical synchronous sequential execution order.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I will try it out. Can you tell me at which point the new_row gets changed to the rowid? I tried `.trigger("reloadGrid")` and tried accessing it but the value is still `new_row`.

Comment: @tempid: I don't understand why you use `new_row` string. What you want to have at the end? If you know the row id which you want to use for the new added row you should the use the value directly. Alternatively you can use `$.jgrid.randId()` to generate unique row id.

Comment: If I do saveRow using code snippet above, and then if I do `getDataIDs();` right after saveRow, the rowid for the record that was just saved is 'new_row', not the integer rowid. For example -- the values returned are = [1,2,3,'new_row']. I want [1,2,3,4,5]. I want the correct row_id after calling saveRow.

Comment: @tempid: I don't understand why you use `'new_row'` as the parameter of `saveRow`. Try to replace it to `$.jgrid.randId()`.

Comment: Oleg -- I read somewhere that the grid internally passes 'new_row' as the parameter to identify new rows. That's why I was passing the same as I thought if I don't pass in 'new_row', the grid won't let me save (silly me!). I think I know what to do now. I'll report back shortly. Thanks again!

Comment: @tempid: You are welcome! In some cases (like in case of [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) if you don't specify any rowid) jqGrid use `"new_row"` as the id of the new row. The problem is only that you can add only *one row* in the way. The next row will have duplicate row ids. So you should specify any *unique* rowid every time when you add the row. I recommend you to use `$.jgrid.randId()` instead of `"new_row"`.

Comment: It looks like the `saveRow` method doesn't accept numbers for rowId. I'm using this - `var newRowId = grid.getDataIDs().length; grid.jqGrid('saveRow', newRowId,'','clientArray', '', SaveFunction,  '', '');` and the function won't fire (I have breakpoints). If I replace the rowId with a string, like, 'newrow123' or something, it works. How do I pass an integer? `$.jgrid.randId()` is not working either. `grid.jqGrid('saveRow', $.jgrid.randId(),'','clientArray', '', SaveFunction, '', '');`

Comment: @tempid: the problem is probably not the code which you posted, but the problem is whether the code will be executed *once* or many times. So you should post more code. In general the id should be not number. It should be just an unique string. If you use `grid.getDataIDs().length` then you can have id duplicates after deleting of a row in the middle of the grid and adding the new row. The method `$.jgrid.randId()` *always* increment the values used to generate the id.